# Rails Gem sanitize - How to whitelist &

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, sanitize

Right now we're using the sanitize gem: https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize

Problem is if you enter "`hello & world`" sanitize is saving that in the DB as:

```
hello &amp; world
```

How can you whitelist the `&` . We want sanitize to remove all possible malicious html and JS/script tags. but we're ok allowing the ampersand.

Ideas? Thanks

Comment: May be Sanitize.clean(html, Sanitize::Config::RELAXED)
# => '&'

Comment: Thanks but RELAXED allows just about everything. I'd like to whitelist & just can't find out how

Comment: @bilash.saha The relaxed config will still html-escape entities, what you posted will still output "Hello &amp; world"

Comment: Use a [`Loofah`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055773/rails-gem-sanitize-how-to-whitelist/59215985#answer-59215985) - it's built in and perfect :)

Answer (score 6):

Sanitize will always transform what is output into html entities for valid html/xhtml.

The best way I can determine is filter the output

```
Sanitize.fragment("hello & world").gsub('&amp;','&') #=> "Hello & world"
```

Comment: This would solve the & character, but would not scale to all the various characters that the html engine used will convert into entities. Trying to keep track of all that would be a headache as well. @agustin's answer below is a better solution IMO

Comment: @ShyamHabarakada The problem I have with Rails' built-in `sanitize()` and `strip_tags`, is that they don't correct malformed markup, so an unmatched `<` character can destroy the page layout. `strip_tags('Strip <ithese tags') #=> "Strip <ithese tags"`, but this is outside of what the question asked for: A way to sanitize, but still allow raw ampersands.

Comment: True that, about malformed markup. We sanitize primarily as a way of preventing HTML from getting into params that should not have HTML. Stripping tags via the built in strip_tags works fine for us on that. It sounds like that's the scenario in this question as well. 

I agree, if you want full sanitization, a better solution that has a proper DOM engine is needed. But for param sanitization, IMO, that seems overkill.

Answer (score 3):

Use the strip_tags() method instead.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize

Comment: This seems like the right solution for the question (and issue I also ran into)

Comment: As of rails-html-sanitizer v1.0.3 strip_tags() escapes & as &amp; https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer/issues/28

Answer (score 2):

UnixMonkey's answer is what we ended up doing.

```
def remove_markup(html_str)
    marked_up = Sanitize.clean html_str

    ESCAPE_SEQUENCES.each do |esc_seq, ascii_seq|
      marked_up = marked_up.gsub('&' + esc_seq + ';', ascii_seq.chr)
    end
    marked_up
  end
```

Where ESCAPE_SEQUENCES was an array of the characters we didn't want escaped.

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers worked for me. The best approach I've found for my use case was using the built in [Loofah](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah) gem:

```
good = '&'
bad = "<script>alert('I am evil');</script>"
greater_than = '>' # << my use case

Loofah.fragment(good).text(encode_special_chars: false)
# => "&"
Loofah.fragment(greater_than).text(encode_special_chars: false)
# => ">"

Loofah.fragment(bad).text(encode_special_chars: false)
# => "alert('I am evil');"

# And just for clarity, without the option passed in:
Loofah.fragment(good).text
# => "&amp;"
```

It's not flawless though, so be incredibly careful:

```
really_bad = "&lt;script&gt;alert('I am evil');&lt;/script&gt;"
Loofah.fragment(really_bad).text(encode_special_chars: false)
# => "<script>alert('I am evil');</script>"
```

More info on the specified method [here](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah/blob/ed153a71cb5ce1c16aded36b5f16875fdac83dfe/lib/loofah/instance_methods.rb#L95).

Definitely the most efficient approach for what I needed to do!

Comment: When you say "built in" what do you mean? Is it built into Rails? It looks like a gem just like sanitize which isn't what I'd consider built in.

Comment: It's included with Rails @Dan. `gem dependency loofah --reverse-dependencies` gives you (among others): `Used by rails-html-sanitizer-1.3.0 (loofah (~> 2.3))`. That Gem itself in built into Rails, see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer): "In Rails 4.2 and above this gem will be responsible for sanitizing HTML fragments in Rails applications".

Answer (score 1):

As of Rails 4.2, `#strip_tags` does not unencode HTML special chars

```
strip_tags("fun & co")
  => "fun &amp; co"
```

Otherwise you'd get the following:

```
strip_tags("&lt;script&gt;")
  => "<script>"
```

If you only want the ampersand I'd suggest filtering the output like @Unixmonkey suggested and keep it to `&` only

```
strip_tags("<bold>Hello & World</bold>").gsub(/&amp;/, "&")
  => "Hello & World"
```